# Code Contracts in C# 4.0+ / Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-contracts

I'm pretty sure I tried to use Code Contracts in C# code by just including a reference to System.Diagnostics.Contracts Namespace http://goo.gl/wZIg54 .

But Code Contracts for .NET page suggests I need to download MSI package. Why is it so? Are Code Contracts built-in into .NET / C# or not?

Comment: OP is just asking for a url to download a library

Comment: It has more bells and whistles.  Like static checking, document generation, code snippet support.  You'll have to RTFM, chapter 6 and up.

Comment: But what this library provides exactly? If I'm not making things out, I used System.Diagnostics.Contracts without downloading a library, because this assembly is here by default.

Comment: @vkelman: The classes are included in the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace, but the tools that utilize them are a separate download. Without the tools the static methods do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@vkelman the calls required to *specify* contracts are part of the basic framework (for example, `Contract.Requires`).  Visual Studio doesn't *do* anything with these, however, unless you've installed the tools that come in the MSI package.